# java nextInt() try catch repeating output more than once

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that accepts two ints within the program using `nextInt();` and have it wrapped in a `try catch` block to stop bad inputs such as doubles or chars.

When multiple wrong inputs are entered the loop repeats that same number of times. I assume this is because my `scan.next()` has to loop around enough times to catch the bad inputs w/o error. Is there a way to know this number on the first run through to make a loop to run next in that many times?

In the output the
  `if(cont == 'N') System.out.print("\nPlease re-enter\n\t:");` will output and mirror the amount of times a mismatched input was written. That is, if I input 3 3.3 it will repeat one extra time, if input s 3.3 2.5 it will repeat three extra times.

I tried putting a loop around `scan.next()` to default it to ten times, but was overboard and I had to input an extra 8 characters before it started reading again. Maybe a while loop but what would its condition be, I tried `while(scan.next() != null){}` but that condition never stopped.

```
//input error checking
char cont = 'Y';
do{
  if(cont == 'N')
    System.out.print("\nPlease re-enter\n\t:");
  cont = 'Y';
  /* to stop the accidential typing of things other
   * than integers from being accepted
   */
  try{
    n1 = scan.nextInt();
    n2 = scan.nextInt();
  }catch(Exception e){
    cont = 'N'; //bad input repeat loop
    scan.next();//stops infinite loop by requesting Scanner try again
  }
} while(cont == 'N');//do loop while told N for continue
```

Comment: can you give an example of wrong input you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want your code to do. From reading what you have posted I assume you want the user to input 2 ints and if he/she doesn't you want to prompt him/her to re-enter something until he/she inputs 2 ints. 
If this is the case I would just add

`scan = new Scanner(br.readLine());`

after this if statement:

`if(cont == 'N')
        {System.out.print("\nPlease re-enter\n\t:");}`

This will solve your looping issue

Comment: where BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Comment: woo!! thanks rz! So it basically just read the rest of the line w/ the scan? then when it went back to input it was ready for user input instead of leftover typed chars?

Comment: any reason why the regular Scanner scan.nextLine() wouldn't have worked?

Comment: mm so scan.next() just reads the next word and then you set scan to contain something else(whatever the user inputs). You should actually take scan.next() out so it doesn't error if the user doesn't enter anything. Where do you want to use scan.nextLine?

Answer (score 0):

First try :

change the line in the exception catch from

```
scan.next();
```

to

```
while(scan.hasNext()){
    scan.next();
}
```

Comment: did not work =( stuck in the while loop i guess, because prompt does not repeat ever

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following in your catch block:

```
while(scan.hasNext())
    scan.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

make it a method and do it with that method.
sth like this:

```
        // do it until getting two Integers
    boolean isItInteger = false;
    while (isItInteger == false) {
        isItInteger = getInt();
    }
    .
    .
    .
        // your method for getting two Integers
    public static boolean getInt() {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            n1 = sc.nextInt();
            n2 = sc.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please re-enter");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i dont think this solve anything. Even if you use different scanners each time, the underlying input stream is unchanged.